# /usr/libexec/routined high CPU

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

A lot of time the MacOS process `/usr/libexec/routined` is using a significant amount of CPU and it has persisted through reboots and even a reinstall.

I read that it is used by Location Services which I have disabled, but nothing has changed.

```
Process:         routined [21860]
Path:            /usr/libexec/routined
Load Address:    0x105277000
Identifier:      routined
Version:         690.0.9
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2020-02-18 17:46:10.513 +0700
Launch Time:     2020-02-17 17:04:08.430 +0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/sample
```

I have verified the file with `codesign` and it doesn't seem to be (replaced by) malware.

```
Executable=/usr/libexec/routined
Identifier=com.apple.routined
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=387 flags=0x2000(library-validation) hashes=5+5 location=embedded
Platform identifier=9
VersionPlatform=1
VersionMin=659200
VersionSDK=659200
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=8850589411172ae27f5eb527ca8c61a9171a64b5
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=8850589411172ae27f5eb527ca8c61a9171a64b5b2626ca4cbc2707a627ae89d
Hash choices=sha256
CMSDigest=8850589411172ae27f5eb527ca8c61a9171a64b5b2626ca4cbc2707a627ae89d
CMSDigestType=2
Page size=4096
CDHash=8850589411172ae27f5eb527ca8c61a9171a64b5
Signature size=4547
Authority=Software Signing
Authority=Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=23
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=68
```

Why is this process using so much of my CPU time? It's constantly using 20-80% CPU. I can kill it but it comes back all the time.

Comment: I'd update the OS first, just on the off-chance it's been fixed since. Use the combo - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2030 - not the delta.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! I installed the combo yesterday and ever since the process isn't very active anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I completely disabled the service as even after installing the combo update it was still using lots of CPU at certain times.

```
sudo mount -rw /
sudo mv /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.routined.plist /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.routined.plist.disabled
```

And then rebooted the system.

Comment: Did you ever miss it or notice a consequence?

Comment: No, never noticed any difference

Comment: Any idea why I can't mount root?  
  
`dondo@Air-Dondo-2 ~ % sudo mount -rw /`
`mounted: Operation not permitted`
`mount: / failed with 77`

Comment: Turning off the LaunchAgent worked for me. `routined` was taking a huge amount of CPU for me (6x more than kernel_task) which is why I decided to disable it.

@dondo, you have to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371908/how-to-make-root-volume-writeable-again-in-catalina) first to mess with the system file system on 10.15 Catalina or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling *routined,* try this:

In your home directory, go look inside ~/Library/Preferences.  Is there a "com.apple.routined.plist" file there?  Delete this plist file & restart your Mac.

One more thing:

If you are using a firewall like Little Snitch, be sure *routined* has outgoing network access.